# How should I define a binary tree in Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, data-structures, tree

In Haskell, a binary tree can be defined in either of the two ways:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

or

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

What are the advantages of choosing one over the other? In which situations is one tree structure a better suit over the other?

Comment: `data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)` should work as well right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It largely depends on your application. The former definition is better if the shape of the tree is determined by the elements, for example if you have a balanced binary tree:

[image]

On the other hand, if your tree acts as a container for unconstrained elements where the shape of the tree doesn't depend on them, it makes more sense to put the values to the leaves.

[This post](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/monoid-fingertree.html) by Heinrich Apfelmus shows very nicely such an approach. He defines

```
data Tree v a = Leaf   v a
              | Branch v (Tree v a) (Tree v a)
```

So values of type `a` are just at leaves, but all nodes (both internal and leaves) are annotated by type `v`, and just by choosing various [monoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) for `v`, we get different interesting data structures.

Answer (score 6):

As @PetrPudlák says, it depends.  The former is better for search trees.  However, the latter version is a (free) *monad*, which can also be useful:

```
instance Monad Tree where
    return = Leaf
    Leaf x >>= f = f x
    Branch t1 t2 >>= f = Branch (t1 >>= f) (t2 >>= f)
```

The `(>>=)` operator corresponds to "substitution at the leaves".

The `Functor` and `Applicative` instances are useful as well.
With GHC 7.10 out they have become mandatory when you define `Monad`.  We can use monad functions to define them:

```
instance Functor Tree where fmap = Control.Monad.liftM
instance Applicative Tree where pure = return; (<*>) = Control.Monad.ap
```

Answer (score 2):

The former is definitely better because it can represent an arbitrary binary tree, which is not the case for the latter. For instance, the second version cannot represent:

1. An empty tree.
2. A tree which has a node that has a left child but not the right one(and vice versa).

Comment: I can understand that a type can be seen to be "definitely better" because it allows to represent more cases, but more flexible does not always equate with "better". I mean -- by the same argument one could say that rose trees are better than binary trees since they can represent more trees.

Comment: @chi Binary trees are explicitly mentioned in the question(if they were not mentioned explicitly, it would be another question). A binary tree is a well-defined notion and the latter version does not allow to represent them.

Comment: It is not better in all cases. Some data structures are implemented as trees that only have data in the leaves. A Huffman code tree would be better represented by the second version, for example. Also, both cases that you mentioned can be represented with the second tree using `Tree (Maybe a)` (that would end up being isomorphic to the first one).

Comment: Oops, actually that wouldn't be isomorphic. I stand by my other point, though.

Answer (score 0):

I consider the latter one to be hardly useful, because it can be flattened to (non-empty) lists, and the only difference is the branch structure. Which is still, however, hard to analyze at the runtime because no additional information is carried by internal nodes; and when you see a branch, you can't say anything about any of its two subtrees. To differ them, you'll have to traverse all over them and essentially kill the O(*log n)* complexity for which we do prefer trees.

If anyone finds a use case for such data structure, please let me know.